# R: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spplot’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Tags: r

I am trying to create a map using the spplot function in R.

I have loaded different libraries that are necessary to carry out this function:

```
> library(mosaic)
> library(latticeExtra)
```

I have read in two data frames. The first, CENSUS, is a table containing 8 different characteristics for 33 Wards in a city. One of these is the Townsend index of deprivation. The second, DISTRICT, is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame containing polygon data for these wards.

```
> DISTRICTS=readShapePoly("DISTRICTS.shp")
> CENSUS=read.csv("CENSUS.csv")
```

I want to map the Townsend index for different wards.

To do this, I have merged the two data frames into a new one, `Census_shape`, and then applied the `spplot` function to this new data frame.

```
> Census_shape=merge(DISTRICTS@data,CENSUS, by.x="name", by.y="WARD", sort=FALSE)
> spplot(Census_shape, "TOWNSEND")
```

However, when I do this, I get this warning.

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spplot’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Where does the error come from? Is it something in my code. Is it more likely a property of my data frames which doesn't work with spplot?

Any advice would greatly help, tanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because `merge` spits out a data frame, which is not surprising because you are feeding it two data frames (the `DISTRICT@data` is just a data frame within the larger `DISTRICT` spatial object).

If you merge your data to preserve it as a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (or whatever), then `spplot` will work as usual. Note that the `sp` package includes a `merge` method for spatial data, see `?sp::merge`.

Note also: you *may* want to switch over to the more modern `sf` package - in my experience it is easier to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was following instructions and hadn't really understood what "@data" stood for.